# Laravel json response from Controller and use Ajax to render in the View

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, laravel

Im working with Laravel 5.1 and have a small issue.

I am sending a JSON response from Instagram's API for most popular media from my controller and want to grab that response in my view with ajax and show it on page to the user without loading the entire page.

I am trying to grab the username and display it in my view to the user.

Right now nothing happens and the console does not show anything, it is empty.

This is my code:

CONROLLER:

```
public function PopularPics(City $city){

    try{
        $jsonData =  $city->getMostPopularPics();
        return response()->json($jsonData);
    }catch(\Exception $ex){
        return $ex->getCode();
    }

}
```

VIEW

```
 <ul id="theData">

    </ul>


    <script>
       $(function(){
          $("#JRequest").click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();

              $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "popular",
                  dataType:"json",
                    success:function(items){
                        $.each(items.data,function(i,item){
                            console.log(item.user.username);
                        });
                    }
              });
          });

       });


    </script>
```

INSTAGRAM JSON

```
{
"data": [{
    "type": "image",
    "users_in_photo": [],
    "filter": "Gotham",
    "tags": [],
    "comments": { ... },
    "caption": {
        "created_time": "1296656006",
        "text": "ãã¼ãâ¥ã¢ããªå§ãã¦ä½¿ã£ã¦ã¿ãã(^^)",
        "from": {
            "username": "cocomiin",
            "full_name": "",
            "type": "user",
            "id": "1127272"
        },
        "id": "26329105"
    },
    "likes": {
        "count": 35,
        "data": [{
            "username": "mikeyk",
            "full_name": "Kevin S",
            "id": "4",
            "profile_picture": "..."
        }, {...subset of likers...}]
    },
    "link": "http://instagr.am/p/BV5v_/",
    "user": {
        "username": "cocomiin",
        "full_name": "Cocomiin",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1127272_75sq_1296145633.jpg",
        "id": "1127272"
    },
    "created_time": "1296655883",
    "images": {
        "low_resolution": {
            "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/01/34d027f155204a1f98dde38649a752ad_6.jpg",
            "width": 306,
            "height": 306
        },
        "thumbnail": {
            "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/01/34d027f155204a1f98dde38649a752ad_5.jpg",
            "width": 150,
            "height": 150
        },
        "standard_resolution": {
            "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/01/34d027f155204a1f98dde38649a752ad_7.jpg",
            "width": 612,
            "height": 612
        }
    },
    "id": "22518783",
    "location": null
},
{
    "type": "video",
    "videos": {
        "low_resolution": {
            "url": "http://distilleryvesper9-13.ak.instagram.com/090d06dad9cd11e2aa0912313817975d_102.mp4",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 480
        },
        "standard_resolution": {
            "url": "http://distilleryvesper9-13.ak.instagram.com/090d06dad9cd11e2aa0912313817975d_101.mp4",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 640
        },
    "users_in_photo": null,
    "filter": "Vesper",
    "tags": [],
    "comments": {
        "data": [{
            "created_time": "1279332030",
            "text": "Love the sign here",
            "from": {
                "username": "mikeyk",
                "full_name": "Mikey Krieger",
                "id": "4",
                "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1242695_75sq_1293915800.jpg"
            },
            "id": "8"
        },
        {
            "created_time": "1279341004",
            "text": "Chilako taco",
            "from": {
                "username": "kevin",
                "full_name": "Kevin S",
                "id": "3",
                "profile_picture": "..."
            },
            "id": "3"
        }],
        "count": 2
    },
    "caption": null,
    "likes": {
        "count": 1,
        "data": [{
            "username": "mikeyk",
            "full_name": "Mikeyk",
            "id": "4",
            "profile_picture": "..."
        }]
    },
    "link": "http://instagr.am/p/D/",
    "user": {
        "username": "kevin",
        "full_name": "Kevin S",
        "profile_picture": "...",
        "id": "3"
    },
    "created_time": "1279340983",
    "images": {
        "low_resolution": {
            "url": "http://distilleryimage2.ak.instagram.com/11f75f1cd9cc11e2a0fd22000aa8039a_6.jpg",
            "width": 306,
            "height": 306
        },
        "thumbnail": {
            "url": "http://distilleryimage2.ak.instagram.com/11f75f1cd9cc11e2a0fd22000aa8039a_5.jpg",
            "width": 150,
            "height": 150
        },
        "standard_resolution": {
            "url": "http://distilleryimage2.ak.instagram.com/11f75f1cd9cc11e2a0fd22000aa8039a_7.jpg",
            "width": 612,
            "height": 612
        }
    },
    "id": "3",
    "location": null
},
...]
}
```

Comment: if you do a `console.log(items)` in the success function. What do you see ?

Comment: in the controller, before return (inside the try) what do you see if you do a `die($jsonData);`

Comment: i see 
array:2 [▼
  "meta" => array:1 [▶]
  "data" => array:24 [▶]
]

Comment: so the controller is definitely sending the data. In the developers tools, do you see a ajax request happening ?

Comment: how do i see the ajax request?under the Network tab?

Comment: yes using the network tab

Comment: always start by digging into the actual request in netowrk tab of browser dev tools (F12) for clues as to where problems might lie

Comment: i cant see an ajax request , should output "ajax" as column?

Comment: under Network i click xhr make the ajax call and i get a 200 back and the Header tab says:

Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01

Comment: if delete the `dataType:"json"` i get :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
in the console..

Comment: Are you sure your routes are configured so that the Ajax URL `url: "popular"` hits that controller function? If you type the URL directly in your browser do you see the JSON data?

Comment: this is my Route

Route::post('popular',[

      'as' => 'popular',
      'uses' => 'MainController@PopularPics'
  ]);

Comment: Yes! If i click the "get pics" button i get i json data data back.